# Nagios: combining passive checks with event handlers

Tags: nagios

**Objective:** I need to monitor a cloud environment with a multitude of remote hosts.

**My problem:**
I have a DB with the current low-level details of the configuration and state of hosts, created on initial scan of the environment. I want the data on my DB to be updated when problems occur, e.g. some network interface is malfunctioning. 
Note: changes in cloud env. setup are caught by listening to the cloud environment message queue, and thus handled separately.

**What I'm looking for:** For scalability reasons, I want to use Nagios passive checks, i.e. have the hosts send state updates using NSCA or NRDP, or anything else that will make this work. Once the check result is received, I want to use an event handler to run a script that will update my configuration DB.
Note: I assume hosts have NIC redundancy, so I don't need to run active ping checks from the server.

I've been trying to figure how to do this, but I only see references to either passive checks alone or event handlers using active checks. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work using a static config for your service.
Heres my static config to execute my python script for disk alerts.

```
define service {
        host_name                       my host
        service_description             / Disk Usage
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_disk!-a '-w 20% -c 10% -p /'!!!!!!
        event_handler                   my_command.py
        initial_state                   o
        max_check_attempts              5
        check_interval                  10
        retry_interval                  1
        check_period                    24x7
        notification_period             24x7
        notifications_enabled           1
        register                        1
        }
```

Firstly, You will need to create a command in Nagios CCM.
(In my case the command is my_command.py)
Define the command name and arguments that should be passed with it.
You can keep your script in /usr/local/nagios/libexec/ which comes as `$USER1$` in Nagios. 
Then define the static config in /usr/local/nagios/etc/static(which may vary based on ur install) as mentioned above.

Hope this helps and that am not too late to answer. ;)